# Is there better approach to model the event? Evolving to discrete event

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact-table

I have a few questions about one of my process implementations in the DW. It would be great if you can provide your suggestion.

**At a high level how business works**

Requester requests quotes --> lenders provide quotes --> requester acts on quote.

I am planning to implement the above as three different fact tables (As we have reporting needs for each of the above steps). I have a question about the implementation of the fact table involving ( lenders provide quotes)

**Details:**

We have an event where lenders provide quotes on a request, and lenders have about 15 mins to provide their quotes.  Lenders at max could provide one quote per request, but they could cancel and provide another quote within the time interval. We record quotes (both canceled + active, if any) from each lender on every request in the operational database (1:M). Also, a quote record is created in DB (more like a template) for every chosen lender on the request even before lenders provide their quote. We update these records upon receiving a quote (evolving event). Since I know the request is only active for 15 mins, can I only load completed requests (w/ over 15 mins) into DW? This way, I can load them as Discrete events.? SLA on stakeholders is 1 hour.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: @NickW Can I get your opinion too?

Comment: You're best to not tie your load process to things that might change (I currently get data every 15 minutes therefore I will load every 15 minutes). You should write a load process that is idempotent - you can run it as frequently or infrequently as required and it will load the correct data regardless. Having said that I don't really understand your question which seems to be: "Since I know that it takes 15 mins, can I only load completed requests (w/ over 15 mins) into DW"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid every request is valid only for 15 mins. All the lenders need to provide while the request is active. I am planning to write a script which only loads quotes on the expired request and avoid loading quotes from active requests which can have change as it still active and might give different results when queried as it is on going. I think this solved idempotent if I am not wrong?

Comment: Yes that's a good idea - don't load confusing / ambiguous / changing data if there is no business need for it. Idempotent just means for example if you run the same load twice, you don't get twice the data, you just get correct data. I'm not sure if there is a specific answer for this question.

Comment: Also with regards to multiple fact tables... A fact is meant to model a "business process" from an analytics perspective. If you can get all of this data into one fact, it's going to make your reporting much easier. But it should only go into one fact if the data is at the same grain, and there are no obvious red flags when combining it. It seems like `Requester requests quotes --> lenders provide quotes --> requester acts on quote.` is a business process that can be modelled in one fact, particularly if you are only loading data when the processes is complete.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks! You are correct I don't think there is a specific answer. I just want to do it in a wrong way. Thanks again.

Comment: My takeaway is: don't split facts if you don't need to. If the data fits into one fact (it sounds like it does), put it into one fact. One of the objectives of star schemas are to make analytics queries easier, and this is done by pre-simplifying the data with prior ETL activities. Trying to report across three facts is difficult.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I think you are correct with regards to having one fact table.  I can combine them into one. The grain would be request-id, lender id, and quote id, uniquely identifying each event in the fact table. I was not thinking of this initially because this would be more like evolving event. I thought of implementing them as separate fact tables, where I can treat them as discrete and would be easier to implement. But since I am planning to load completed requests, it makes sense to have a single fact.